# Sublimelinter Not working on MacOSX but works on WIndows

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I am successfully using Sublimelinter within a windows environment , Recently I installed Sublime on a Mac oSX and connected my existing windows sublime settings. However My sublimeLinter package does not seem to work on the Mac version. Is there I need to do extra?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add few dev packages:

> "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
>    "eslint": "^3.17.1",
>   "eslint-config-standard": "^7.0.1",
>       "eslint-plugin-promise":> "^3.5.0",
>    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
>   "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.1.1",

and an

> .eslintrc

&

> .eslintignore

file